# Relax function broken in 3.3.1?

Tags: mesh, add-on, edit-mode

I enabled the Mesh Edit tool add-on in my install of 3.3.1 after using 2.9 for awhile.

Problem is that it no longer works like it used to.

It seems to magnetize stray vertices for no clear reason, when it previously didn't in past blender iterations.

Any work around? I never see this brought up online. :/

[image: Abnormal behavior]